# rajawali and vuforia 3d model positioning

Tags: vuforia, rajawali

I have followed the RajawaliVuforia tutorial and integrated the rajawali with vuforia CloudReco and i am able to get the 3D model but model is not positioned properly in target image center and also if i move camera close or up, the model is positioning out of the target image. Can someone let me know what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia passes the position (Vector3) and orientation (Quaternion) to Rajawali. Rajawali then uses this to position and rotate the model. This might interfere with animations applied to the model. If you're using animations or if you're setting the position manually you'll get unpredictable results. The reason for this is that the position is set twice on each frame.

The way to fix this is to put your 3D model in a container (an empty BaseObject3D). Vuforia's position and orientation will be applied to this container and not your 3D model. This way you can animate the model without getting unpredictable results.